# How to create multi-scale variables from landcover data

Tags: qgis, raster, modelling, maxent, distribution

I have calculated raster files with values of 0 and 1 for each landcover attribute I am interested in. I would like to make multiple raster files containing different cell sizes. e.g 100m2, 500m2, 1km2, 2km2 5km2 etc. that denote the coverage of each landcover attribute within each cell. How can I do this?

The purpose is for multi-scale distribution modelling using MaxEnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the `Create Grid` tool to make a grid with rectangular polygons of the desired size. Make a separate grid layer for each cell size; if you have X number of cell sizes, you will create X grid layers.
2. Use the `zonal histogram` tool to summarize landcover within each grid cell.
3. `Rasterize` the vector grid. Run once for every landcover type, for each grid layer. If you have Y number of landcover types, the total number of output rasters will be X * Y.

There's probably also a method that works entirely with rasters. I'm not sure which method would be faster.

---

Note:

It's not clear from the wording of your question if your landcover raster data has

- all landcover types in one raster with each unique value representing a particular landcover type (eg forest = 0.1, grassland = 0.2, etc)

-or-

- each landcover type stored in a separate raster, such that this_landcover_type = 1, other_landcover_type = 0

This answer assumes you have the second type of data. If you have the first type of data, split your raster into separate rasters of the second type.